# creation of filebeat config-map via terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, filebeat

we have a deamonset of filebeat managed by terraform. for the creation we have used the provider gavinbunney/kubectl" and declared all filbeat objects as ressources in filebeat.tf module as below.

the problem is that, for the creation of the config map with this method, we have a cm that's starts like this

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  **yaml_body: |**
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
```

instead of

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
**filebeat.yml: |**
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
```

## which makes the pods to fail. please help. I need to pass the correct cm to terraform.

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "ServiceAccount" {
  yaml_body = <<-EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
EOF
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "ClusterRole" {
  yaml_body = <<-EOF
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources:
  - namespaces
  - pods
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources:
    - replicasets
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources:
    - jobs
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
EOF
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "role" {
  yaml_body = <<-EOF
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - coordination.k8s.io
    resources:
      - leases
    verbs: ["get", "create", "update"]
EOF
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "filebeat-kubeadm-config" {
  yaml_body = <<-EOF
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: filebeat-kubeadm-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - configmaps
    resourceNames:
      - kubeadm-config
    verbs: ["get"]
EOF
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "ClusterRoleBinding" {
  yaml_body = <<-EOF
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
EOF
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "RoleBinding" {
  yaml_body = <<-EOF
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: filebeat
    namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
EOF
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "filebeat-kubeadm-configRB" {
  yaml_body = <<-EOF
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat-kubeadm-config
  namespace: kube-system
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: filebeat
    namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: filebeat-kubeadm-config
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
EOF
}


resource "kubernetes_config_map" "filebeat_config_map" {
  metadata {
    name      = "filebeat-config"
    namespace = "kube-system"
    labels = {
      k8s-app = "filebeat"
    }
  }

  data = {
    yaml_body = <<-EOF
      filebeat.inputs:
      - type: container
        multiline.type: pattern
        multiline.pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}'
        multiline.negate: true
        multiline.match: after
        symlinks: true
        paths:
          - /var/log/containers/*xxx*.log
        include_lines: ['xxx-LOG','REQUEST']
        processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: $${NODE_NAME}
            in_cluster: true
            default_matchers.enabled: false
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: /var/log/containers/
      output.logstash:
        hosts: ["${var.logstash}"]
    EOF
  }
}



resource "kubectl_manifest" "deamonset" {
  yaml_body = <<-EOF
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
      - name: filebeat
        image: xxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/filebeat:8.6.0
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
          "-e",
        ]
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: "${var.logstash_server}"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "${var.logstash_port}"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
          value: elastic
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
          value: ${var.logstash_password}
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID
          value:
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH
          value:
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          # If using Red Hat OpenShift uncomment this:
          #privileged: true
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: filebeat.yml
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0640
          name: filebeat-config
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      # data folder stores a registry of read status for all files, so we don't send everything again on a Filebeat pod restart
      - name: data
        hostPath:
          # When filebeat runs as non-root user, this directory needs to be writable by group (g+w).
          path: /var/lib/filebeat-data
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
EOF
}
```

Expected result

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  filebeat.yml: |
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      multiline.type: pattern
      multiline.pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}'
      multiline.negate: true
      multiline.match: after
      symlinks: true
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*xxxxx*.log
      include_lines: ['xxx-LOG','REQUEST']
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
            in_cluster: true
            default_matchers.enabled: false
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: /var/log/containers/
    output.logstash:
      hosts: ["IP:port"]
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "15162378"
  uid: cc8c1296-42de-4a72-a698-3149bb6979c1



what we got

apiVersion: v1
data:
  yaml_body: |
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      multiline.type: pattern
      multiline.pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}'
      multiline.negate: true
      multiline.match: after
      symlinks: true
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*xxxx*.log
      include_lines: ['xxx-LOG','REQUEST']
      processors:
      - add_kubernetes_metadata:
          host: ${NODE_NAME}
          in_cluster: true
          default_matchers.enabled: false
          matchers:
          - logs_path:
              logs_path: /var/log/containers/
    output.logstash:
      hosts: ["ip:port"]
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      
  creationTimestamp: "2023-05-02T12:10:47Z"
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
```

Comment: The first example is correct and valid yaml but your desired result is not valid yaml.